# uniform convergence of two variable-functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence

Let $f(x,y)$ be a real-valued two-variable function on the plane.

(1). $\lim_{x\to\infty,y\to\infty}f(x,y)$ exists.

(2). for any fixed $y$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x,y)$ exists and converges uniformly for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$.

(3). for any fixed $x$, $\lim_{y\to\infty}f(x,y)$ exists and converges uniformly for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Question: Whether does (1) imply (2) and (3) or not? I want to find a sufficient condition of (2) and (3).

Answer (score 0):

The reverse is true. The formal statement (i.e., the Moore-Osgood theorem) is as below:

Let $x\in X$ and $y \in Y$.

(1) If $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x,y)$ exists and converges uniformly for all $y \in Y$.

(2) If $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{y\to\infty} f(x,y)$ exists for any $x\in X$ (not required to be uniformly convergent).

Then we have $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty ,y \to \infty } f(x,y)$ exists.

Comment: This does not adress the question.